# Crystal report - how to add image to background

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, watermark

I have a list of names that I pass through stored procedure in my report.
I (as administrator) can upload some image that have empty white space. In that white space I need to add each name in report.
Can I somehow put some section with fixed size for images and add text field (name) over the section. And when create report pass image in report to display it in this section?
Is this possible?

Comment: Add from a link-only answer by [craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134367/craig)  Here's another approach: [Crystal Report: Include Terms and Conditions on a Form Letter](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/23/crystal-report-include-terms-and-conditions-on-a-form-letter/)